# WPF StoryBoard.Completed event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, storyboard

I have an animation before closing the main window, like the following code shows. Problem is the `StoryBoard.Completed` is not firing. Any clues what is causing this?

**Code**

```
DoubleAnimation dblAnimX = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.0, new  Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
dblAnimX.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, this);

DoubleAnimation dblAnimY = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)));
dblAnimY.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, this);

Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.SetTarget(dblAnimX, this);
Storyboard.SetTarget(dblAnimY, this);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dblAnimX, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dblAnimY, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));

story.Children.Add(dblAnimX);
story.Children.Add(dblAnimY);
story.Begin(this);

story.Completed += (o, s) => { this.Close(); };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Storyboard animation doesn't reset position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810216/c-sharp-storyboard-animation-doesnt-reset-position)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add the Completed handler before calling Begin:

```
story.Completed += (o, s) => Close();
story.Begin(this);
```

---

The reason for this behaviour is that the Completed handler is attached to an internal Clock object that is created during Begin. See the Remarks section in [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx):

> Although this event handler appears to be associated with a timeline,
>   it actually registers with the Clock created for this timeline. For
>   more information, see the Timing Events Overview.