# Animation.Completed event is not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an endless animation that hast to be reverted in certain circumstances. When it is reverted it has to run only once.

I initialize the animation in the constructor like this:

```
  public RailComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RootCanvas.DataContext = this;                

        //RailAnimation
        _railAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
            To = -_animationTo,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TrackRunningTime))
        };

        ...

    }
```

And then add it to the Storyboard:

```
    private void InitializeAnimations()
    {
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_railAnimation, RailImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_railAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));

        AddAnimation(_railAnimation);
        ...
    }
```

Where AddAnimation is defined as:

```
 protected void AddAnimation(DoubleAnimation animation)
    {
        saveAnimationHandling(() => Railstoryboard.Children.Add(animation));
    }

    private void saveAnimationHandling(Action animationAction)
    {

        TimeSpan current = GetCurrentStoryboardTime();
        StopStoryboard();

        animationAction();

        StartStoryboard();
        Railstoryboard.Seek(current);
        SetVelocity();
    }
```

I handle several Animations via the same Storyboard (i.e. add them or remove them). That's why I have to 'safely' handle them. The above code works just as intended (or hides its misbehaviour well.) But when I try to change some properties and add a Completed event, it never fires:

```
private void UpdateDirection(bool isBackward)
{
    PauseRailStoryBoard();
    var x = -RailImage.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
    var duration = x / _animationTo * TrackRunningTime;

    _railAnimation.To = 0;
    _railAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
    _railAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);

    _railAnimation.Completed += _backwardRailAnimation_Completed;

    ResumeRailStoryBoard();
 }

 void _backwardRailAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     _railAnimation.Completed -= _backwardRailAnimation_Completed;
 }
```

**Edit - alternate version that does also not work (saveHandleAnimation is ofc protected for this version):**

```
private void UpdateDirection(bool isBackward)
{   
    saveHandleAnimation(() =>
    {
        var x = -RailImage.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
        var duration = x / _animationTo * TrackRunningTime;

        _railAnimation.To = 0;
        _railAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
        _railAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1);

        _railAnimation.Completed += _backwardRailAnimation_Completed;
    });
}
```

I added a breakpoint into the event handling but it never seems to fire although the animation stops. Any pointers as to why would be very welcome. I did the very same thing with animations that are not endless and it seems to work just fine (I used a different Storyboard there).

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14183515/1136211) to [StoryBoard.Completed event not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14183121/1136211).

Comment: Yes, I know I have to add the Animation before calling Begin. That's exactly what "saveAnimationHandling" is for. It reinitializes the Storyboard each time a new Animation is added. I also tried to apply this pattern to adding my Handler. But it does not work. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Just a guess, but instead of modifying the existing `_railAnimation` instance you might create a new DoubleAnimation instance.