# C# Storyboard animation doesn't reset position

Tags: c#, storyboard, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I have generated a XAML file which contains a scrollviewer with studentnames and a graph. When I click on one of these names, the respective lines will fly in (grow from small to correct size aswell) from the top left and stop at the right position on the axes.

When I click on another name it will trigger the same thing but when these stop at the right position, the former lines fly out of the screen and shrink down through the bottom right.

This all works until I press a name I have already pressed before. These lines then start out small, stay small, and immediately fly out the bottom right, instead of stopping on the axes with its proper size.

I've tried stopping the animation but that doesn't seem to be working, any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void selectStudent(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Duration duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));

        if (line01 != null)
        {
            line1Animation1.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line1Animation1.Duration = duration;
            line1Animation1.From = line01.X1;
            line1Animation1.To = (line01.X1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line1Animation2.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line1Animation2.Duration = duration;
            line1Animation2.From = line01.Y1;
            line1Animation2.To = (line01.Y1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line1Animation3.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line1Animation3.Duration = duration;
            line1Animation3.From = line01.X2;
            line1Animation3.To = (line01.X2 * 0.1) + 800;
            line1Animation4.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line1Animation4.Duration = duration;
            line1Animation4.From = line01.Y2;
            line1Animation4.To = (line01.Y2 * 0.1) + 800;
            storyboard1.Begin();

            line2Animation1.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line2Animation1.Duration = duration;
            line2Animation1.From = line02.X1;
            line2Animation1.To = (line02.X1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line2Animation2.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line2Animation2.Duration = duration;
            line2Animation2.From = line02.Y1;
            line2Animation2.To = (line02.Y1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line2Animation3.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line2Animation3.Duration = duration;
            line2Animation3.From = line02.X2;
            line2Animation3.To = (line02.X2 * 0.1) + 800;
            line2Animation4.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line2Animation4.Duration = duration;
            line2Animation4.From = line02.Y2;
            line2Animation4.To = (line02.Y2 * 0.1) + 800;
            storyboard2.Begin();

            line3Animation1.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line3Animation1.Duration = duration;
            line3Animation1.From = line03.X1;
            line3Animation1.To = (line03.X1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line3Animation2.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line3Animation2.Duration = duration;
            line3Animation2.From = line03.Y1;
            line3Animation2.To = (line03.Y1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line3Animation3.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line3Animation3.Duration = duration;
            line3Animation3.From = line03.X2;
            line3Animation3.To = (line03.X2 * 0.1) + 800;
            line3Animation4.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line3Animation4.Duration = duration;
            line3Animation4.From = line03.Y2;
            line3Animation4.To = (line03.Y2 * 0.1) + 800;
            storyboard3.Begin();

            line4Animation1.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line4Animation1.Duration = duration;
            line4Animation1.From = line04.X1;
            line4Animation1.To = (line04.X1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line4Animation2.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line4Animation2.Duration = duration;
            line4Animation2.From = line04.Y1;
            line4Animation2.To = (line04.Y1 * 0.1) + 800;
            line4Animation3.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line4Animation3.Duration = duration;
            line4Animation3.From = line04.X2;
            line4Animation3.To = (line04.X2 * 0.1) + 800;
            line4Animation4.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            line4Animation4.Duration = duration;
            line4Animation4.From = line04.Y2;
            line4Animation4.To = (line04.Y2 * 0.1) + 800;
            storyboard4.Begin();

            titleActive.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        line01 = (Line)FindName(((Border)sender).Name + "_Line_1");
        storyboard1 = (Storyboard)FindName(line01.Name + "_StoryboardLine");
        line1Animation1String = line01.Name + "_lineAnimation1";
        line1Animation1 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line1Animation1String);
        line1Animation2String = line01.Name + "_lineAnimation2";
        line1Animation2 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line1Animation2String);
        line1Animation3String = line01.Name + "_lineAnimation3";
        line1Animation3 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line1Animation3String);
        line1Animation4String = line01.Name + "_lineAnimation4";
        line1Animation4 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line1Animation4String);

        line02 = (Line)FindName(((Border)sender).Name + "_Line_2");
        storyboard2 = (Storyboard)FindName(line02.Name + "_StoryboardLine");
        line2Animation1String = line02.Name + "_lineAnimation1";
        line2Animation1 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line2Animation1String);
        line2Animation2String = line02.Name + "_lineAnimation2";
        line2Animation2 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line2Animation2String);
        line2Animation3String = line02.Name + "_lineAnimation3";
        line2Animation3 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line2Animation3String);
        line2Animation4String = line02.Name + "_lineAnimation4";
        line2Animation4 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line2Animation4String);

        line03 = (Line)FindName(((Border)sender).Name + "_Line_3");
        storyboard3 = (Storyboard)FindName(line03.Name + "_StoryboardLine");
        line3Animation1String = line03.Name + "_lineAnimation1";
        line3Animation1 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line3Animation1String);
        line3Animation2String = line03.Name + "_lineAnimation2";
        line3Animation2 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line3Animation2String);
        line3Animation3String = line03.Name + "_lineAnimation3";
        line3Animation3 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line3Animation3String);
        line3Animation4String = line03.Name + "_lineAnimation4";
        line3Animation4 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line3Animation4String);

        line04 = (Line)FindName(((Border)sender).Name + "_Line_4");
        storyboard4 = (Storyboard)FindName(line04.Name + "_StoryboardLine");
        line4Animation1String = line04.Name + "_lineAnimation1";
        line4Animation1 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line4Animation1String);
        line4Animation2String = line04.Name + "_lineAnimation2";
        line4Animation2 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line4Animation2String);
        line4Animation3String = line04.Name + "_lineAnimation3";
        line4Animation3 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line4Animation3String);
        line4Animation4String = line04.Name + "_lineAnimation4";
        line4Animation4 = (DoubleAnimation)FindName(line4Animation4String);

        titleActive = (TextBlock)FindName(((Border)sender).Name + "_Title");

        line1Animation1.Duration = duration;
        line1Animation1.From = (line01.X1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line1Animation1.To = line01.X1;
        line1Animation2.Duration = duration;
        line1Animation2.From = (line01.Y1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line1Animation2.To = line01.Y1;
        line1Animation3.Duration = duration;
        line1Animation3.From = (line01.X2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line1Animation3.To = line01.X2;
        line1Animation4.Duration = duration;
        line1Animation4.From = (line01.Y2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line1Animation4.To = line01.Y2;
        storyboard1.Begin();

        line2Animation1.Duration = duration;
        line2Animation1.From = (line02.X1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line2Animation1.To = line02.X1;
        line2Animation2.Duration = duration;
        line2Animation2.From = (line02.Y1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line2Animation2.To = line02.Y1;
        line2Animation3.Duration = duration;
        line2Animation3.From = (line02.X2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line2Animation3.To = line02.X2;
        line2Animation4.Duration = duration;
        line2Animation4.From = (line02.Y2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line2Animation4.To = line02.Y2;
        storyboard2.Begin();

        line3Animation1.Duration = duration;
        line3Animation1.From = (line03.X1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line3Animation1.To = line03.X1;
        line3Animation2.Duration = duration;
        line3Animation2.From = (line03.Y1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line3Animation2.To = line03.Y1;
        line3Animation3.Duration = duration;
        line3Animation3.From = (line03.X2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line3Animation3.To = line03.X2;
        line3Animation4.Duration = duration;
        line3Animation4.From = (line03.Y2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line3Animation4.To = line03.Y2;
        storyboard3.Begin();

        line4Animation1.Duration = duration;
        line4Animation1.From = (line04.X1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line4Animation1.To = line04.X1;
        line4Animation2.Duration = duration;
        line4Animation2.From = (line04.Y1 - 250) * 0.1;
        line4Animation2.To = line04.Y1;
        line4Animation3.Duration = duration;
        line4Animation3.From = (line04.X2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line4Animation3.To = line04.X2;
        line4Animation4.Duration = duration;
        line4Animation4.From = (line04.Y2 - 250) * 0.1;
        line4Animation4.To = line04.Y2;
        storyboard4.Begin();

        line01.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        line02.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        line03.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        line04.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        titleActive.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

XAML: (lines from 1 person, couldn't fit whole file)

```
<Line Stroke="Darkgreen" StrokeThickness="2" X1="212.97500000000002" X2="350.0" Y1="350.0" Y2="190.53124999999997" x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <Line.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1_StoryboardLine">
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1_lineAnimation1" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1_lineAnimation2" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1_lineAnimation3" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1_lineAnimation4" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
    <Line Stroke="Darkgreen" StrokeThickness="2" X1="509.86249999999995" X2="350.0" Y1="350.0" Y2="190.53124999999997" x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <Line.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2_StoryboardLine">
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2_lineAnimation1" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2_lineAnimation2" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2_lineAnimation3" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2_lineAnimation4" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
    <Line Stroke="Darkgreen" StrokeThickness="2" X1="350.0" X2="212.97500000000002" Y1="487.025" Y2="350.0" x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <Line.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3_StoryboardLine">
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3_lineAnimation1" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3_lineAnimation2" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3_lineAnimation3" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3_lineAnimation4" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
    <Line Stroke="Darkgreen" StrokeThickness="2" X1="509.86249999999995" X2="350.0" Y1="350.0" Y2="487.025" x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <Line.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4_StoryboardLine">
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4_lineAnimation1" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4_lineAnimation2" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y1" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4_lineAnimation3" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" />
              <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4_lineAnimation4" Storyboard.TargetName="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Use completed event to stop or remove storyboards like this:

```
 <Storyboard Completed="storyboard_Completed" x:Name="Marilyn_Williamson_Line_1_StoryboardLine">
```

and in code behind :

```
 private void storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string StoryBoardName = ((ClockGroup)sender).Timeline.Name;
        if (StoryBoardName == "storyboard1") { storyboard1.Stop(); storyboard1.Remove(); }
    }
```

2 - Put `storyboard.Stop();` before each `storyboard.Begin();`